# Solution verification: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}+x^2}{2x-x^2} = -1$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

I am trying to find the following limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}+x^2}{2x-x^2}$$

and I did the following steps:

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
&\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}+x^2}{2x-x^2} \\
&\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2}+1\right)}{x^2\left(\frac{2x}{x^2}-1\right)} \\
& \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\cancel{x^2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2}+1\right)}{\cancel{x^2}\left(\frac{2\cancel{x}}{\cancel{x^2}}-1\right)}\\
& \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2}+1\right)}{\left(\frac{2}{x}-1\right)} \\
\end{align}

Now here, the top portion goes to $0$ because the there is a larger power of $x$ in the denominator leaving only a $+1$ on top. On the bottom, the same thing happens, $\frac{2}{x}$ goes to $0$ and we left with $-1$ in the denominator. Therefore

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}+x^2}{2x-x^2} = -1$$

Is my solution correct and did I take the right steps with the correct logic?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Things will more clear if we put $\sqrt x=\frac1h$

Comment: Very good example of how a question should be asked. Detailing your own work helps others to provide a better answer or suggestion.(+1)

Comment: Would the @downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent work. You've made a correct and tight case for the limit being $-1$.

Just replace

> Now here, the top portion goes to $0$ because the there is a larger power of $x$ in the denominator leaving only $(+1)$ on top.

With

> Now here, the top portion goes to $1$ because in the first term of the numerator there is a larger power of $x$ in the denominator leaving only the term of $(+)1$ on top. On the bottom...

You could also argue that in the numerator, $\dfrac {\sqrt x}{x^2} = \dfrac 1{x^{3/2}} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Nice explanation. Well done! :)

Comment: @amWhy: Get another TU +1

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks good! I would be a bit more precise about "the top portion goes to $0$," but your reasoning is just fine.